# Tableau filter is not working for SETs that are created using Tableau Extension API

Tags: javascript, filter, tableau-api

I have created an export to CSV extension in tableau to embed it into dashboard for users to download the data.
however we have condition and is, i need to set the filter using applyFilterAsync to some value before download and reset that filter using same applyFilterAsync with parameters of 'filtername' and 'value' and filterUpdateType.ADD to add and REMOVE to remove.

This is not working in case of SETs, Rangefilters, Dimensions and all.

Need your help resolve this issue.

**Clearing the filters:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = worksheets[i];
    if (sheetList.indexOf(sheet.name) > -1) {
      sheet.getFiltersAsync());      
      sheet.clearFilterAsync('IN/OUT(DownloadSet)');
      console.log('Filter Cleared');
    }
  }
```

**Apply the filter after download:**

```
sheet.applyFilterAsync('IN/OUT(DownloadSet)','In',tableau.FilterUpdateType.Replace);
```

Please your help to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since these are async functions, they return a promise.  Your code should look like:

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < worksheets.length; i++) {
        var sheet = worksheets[i];
        if (sheetList.indexOf(sheet.name) > -1) {
          sheet.getFiltersAsync())
          .then(function() { 
             sheet.clearFilterAsync('IN/OUT(DownloadSet)');
          })
          .then(function() { 
             console.log('Filter Cleared');
          })      
        }
      }
```

Same with the applyFilterAsync:

```
sheet.applyFilterAsync('IN/OUT(DownloadSet)',['In'],tableau.FilterUpdateType.Replace)
    .then(function() {
     // do something
    })
```

Without seeing more context/errors this is probably what is causing your issues.

EDIT: Set filters automatically evaluate to the 'In' value.  I'm looking into if you have the right syntax for a set filter.

UPDATE:. This should be the right asynchronous call:

For applyFilterAsync you need to pass an array of strings, `sheet.applyFilterAsync('IN/OUT(DownloadSet)',['In'],tableau.FilterUpdateType.Replace)`

Comment: Hi tagyoureit, thanks for your response. The issue is fixed after replacing the filter in the initial step.

Comment: Great!  Would you mark my answer as correct, please?